# Constructing a MySQL to determine "length of lifecycle" by multiple identities of the same value

Tags: mysql

Bit of a background: Bees receive a numbered-color tag that is used to identify them. The tags need to be reused because there are too many bees. However, a particular tag is never used concurrently and the bees' birth and death dates are recorded.

The Data structure:

```
TABLE: tags
id  bee_id  tag_date      colony_id     events      tagged_by
=================================================================================
1   G23 2013-06-01  1       birth       ET
2   Y35 2013-06-03  1       birth       ET
3   G23 2013-07-01  NULL        death       ET
4   G23 2013-07-02  2       birth       ET
5   W64 2013-07-03  1       birth       ET
6   Y35 2013-07-15  NULL        death       ET
```

THE DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
bee_id  Status  Birth Date Death Date
======================================================
G23 Dead    2013-06-01  2013-07-01
G23 Alive   2013-07-02  NULL
Y35 Dead    2013-06-03  2013-07-15
```

What I tried (and failed)

```
select * from
   ( select *
      from tags
      order by tag_date
      where events = "birth"
      limit 1 ) as births
   group by `bee_id`
```

Comment: is that `&` supposed to be a `*` in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this structure, you want to focus on "births" and find the next "death" for each one.  I think a correlated subquery is the easiest way to express this query:

```
select t.bee_id, (case when t.death_date is null then 'Alive' else 'Dead' end) as status,
       t.tag_date as birth_date, t.death_date
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.tag_date
              from tags t2
              where t2.bee_id = t.bee_id and
                    t2.events = 'death' and
                    t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date
              order by t2.tag_date
              limit 1
             ) as death_date
      from tags t
      where t.events = 'birth'
     ) t
group by t.bee_id, t.tag_date;
```

The subquery finds the first death record after each birth.  Note:  this structure assumes that your data is as you say it is.  That is, if you have two births in a row on the same `bee_id`, then they are both counted.  And both will have the same death date, if a date follows.

Comment: Thanks kindly for your help! I can follow what you've constructed but would never be able to write it myself! I have a bit of a problem running the query: MySQL complains that selecting "t.tag_date as birth_date" is problematic both on the second line and the last one. If I remove those two bits, I get another error about the subquery returning more than one line. If I limit the result of the innermost subquery to 1, then it works!